# Remove non-matching parent elements in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, wix, xslt-1.0

- I need to remove all `Component` elements and their corresponding `ComponentRef` elements, where the `Component` child element `File` attribute `Source` is NOT a `dll` file?
- I have the evaluation function for the `Source` string value i.e. `{substring(wix:File/@Source, string-length(wix:File/@Source) - 2)}='dll'` returns true for `Source` values that contain `dll`
- But I don't know how to use the function to remove the last two `Component` elements (with their children) as well as the corresponding last two `ComponentRef` elements (mapped by `Id` attribute)?

#### Source XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETFOLDER">
            <Component Id="cmpA733DB49D89AC9CEA2EDFAAEE51992E7" Guid="{F3412A8F-5718-45AB-9E6F-7B802BCC0EED}">
                <File Source="$(var.WixSlave.TargetDir)\protobuf-net.dll" Id="fil910D6DB28382BAB5A9DF0ACBD5095ADE" KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmpF1D751B9621E283AD7BDAA8BC6997338" Guid="{20C09DBB-C8D6-43CF-A9D6-C823850F86F6}">
                <File Source="$(var.WixSlave.TargetDir)\client.wyc" Id="fil7454A527FA7C3918A537EB96235C9F5F" KeyPath="yes"  />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp8CDA926DD93F7CEFBF8FFF444D5828F4" Guid="{2243D9D8-C172-4FFE-AEBE-43659294E55D}">
                <File Source="$(var.WixSlave.TargetDir)\protobuf-net.pdb" Id="fil3EA19C07C51C4E31D37065B3A8620713" KeyPath="yes"  />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="Dlls">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpA733DB49D89AC9CEA2EDFAAEE51992E7" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpF1D751B9621E283AD7BDAA8BC6997338" />
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp8CDA926DD93F7CEFBF8FFF444D5828F4" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

#### Dysfunctional XSLT Stub

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="wix:File[{substring(wix:File/@Source, string-length(wix:File/@Source) - 2)}!='dll']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- This XSLT does not work in many ways, firstly the second `match` complains, and I'm not sure what is wrong with the expression..
- Even if that worked, how would you always retain `DirectoryRef` while removing the mismatching `Component` and child `File` elements?
- Removing the corresponding `ComponentRef` elements is missing altogether?

#### Desired XML Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="TARGETFOLDER">
            <Component Id="cmpA733DB49D89AC9CEA2EDFAAEE51992E7" Guid="{F3412A8F-5718-45AB-9E6F-7B802BCC0EED}">
                <File Source="$(var.WixSlave.TargetDir)\protobuf-net.dll" Id="fil910D6DB28382BAB5A9DF0ACBD5095ADE" KeyPath="yes" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="Dlls">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmpA733DB49D89AC9CEA2EDFAAEE51992E7" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: it complains because it doesn't like the `{}`. If you removed the `{}` from the XPath in your match it would let it run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would go about it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:key name="component-id" match="//wix:Component[substring(wix:File/@Source, string-length(wix:File/@Source) - 2) != 'dll']" use="@Id"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wix:Component[@Id = key('component-id', @Id)/@Id]"/>

    <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[@Id = key('component-id', @Id)/@Id]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The idea is rather simple. Tell XSLT processor to build an index of those Component nodes we want removed and then suppress the `xsl:copy` with a matching template.

Comment: Works perfectly in my initial test!

Comment: sure. you can also consider using `contains` for the "dll" test. something like this looks somewhat better than substring: `match="//wix:Component[not(contains(wix:File/@Source, 'dll'))]`.

Comment: if you would like to optimize it even further you could have one template handling all exclusions for you: `<xsl:template match="*[@Id = key('component-id', @Id)/@Id]"/>`. It assumes that you do, in fact, want to exclude all other nodes that might have their `@Id` point out to those `Component`s.

Comment: @PavelVeller: Good answer, +1. Do note that starting a match pattern with `//` is useless: `match="//wix:Component/someStepExpression"` is equivalent to `match="wix:Component/someStepExpression"`. You also don't need the default namespace defined in the transformation and better get rid of it.